# Upon @post.create I get a no method error - I cannot track down why this method is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a post controller and keep getting a no method error which is triggered by @post.create.
Below is the error message, which I cannot track down where this is coming from - the nomethod erro r gives no clues.

error:

```
undefined method `each' for "":String
```

controller/source of error: posts_controller.rb

```ruby
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  require 'securerandom'
  before_action :set_post, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  
  # GET /posts or /posts.json
  def index
    @city = request.location.city
    @category = Category.find_by(title: params[:category_name])
    @posts = Post.where(section_id: params[:section_id], category_name:   params[:category_name], section_name: params[:section_name])
    if params[:street] != nil && params[:city] != nil && params[:postal_code] != nil && params[:country_code] != nil
      @posts = @posts.near(["%#{params[:street]}%","%#{params[:city]}%","%#{params[:country_code]}%"].compact.join(', '), :distance)
    end
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@posts) do |post, marker|
      marker.lat post.latitude
      marker.lng post.longitude
    end
  end
  
  # GET /posts/1 or /posts/1.json
  def show
  end
  
  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
    @post.section_id = params[:section_id]
    @post.category_name = params[:category_name]
    @post.section_name = params[:section_name]
  end
  
  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  # POST /posts or /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.create(post_params)
    @post.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
    if params[:city] == nil || params[:country_code] == nil ||  params[:title] == nil
      flash[:notice] = "You must fill in a Title, City, and Country to save."
      redirect_to new_section_post_path(section_id: @post.section_id, category_name: @post.category_name, section_name: @post.section_name)
    else
      @post.geocode
      
      respond_to do |format|
        if @post.save
          format.html { redirect_to section_post_url(id: @post.id, section_id: @post.section_id), notice: "Post was successfully created." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
        else
          format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
  
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1 or /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to section_post_url(id: @post.id, section_id: @post.section_id), notice: "Post was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  
  # DELETE /posts/1 or /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: "Post was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  
  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :uuid, :latitude, :longitude, :category_name, :section_name, :city, :postal_code, :country_code, :flags, :section_id, :street, :content)
  end
end
```

error log:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4178)



NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "":String

    other_array.each { |val| raise_on_type_mismatch!(val) }
               ^^^^^):

 app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:38:in `create'
```

model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :section
has_many :flags
has_many :messages
geocoded_by :address
has_rich_text :content

def address
[street, city, country_code].compact.join(', ')
end
end
```

~

That is all the info I have and am just wondering if anyone has seen this error before?  It is clearly activerecord but what I am missing isn't clear.  I only enter strings in the migration, all my parameters entered are strings, just flags and section_id are integers.

model.create throws error I cannot track down.

Comment: I think we need to see your model as well. Also I do spot this potential error: `if params[:city] = nil || params[:country_code] = nil ||  params[:title] = nil` is assigning those params to nil, not doing a comparison like you're probably expecting. To do a comparison, do `params[:city] == nil` or `params[:city].nil?`

Comment: thank you steev, you are right, i guess I was not thinking, but still get the no method error on each in create

Comment: The issue is happening here -- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e90bc0d9e9e5d146bb4a16eb56028ec29a4ea7d7/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L235. My guess is you are not using id as the primary key on the model and did not tell ActiveRecord that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to add a collection of `Flag` objects related to a `Post`, but the way you're doing it now, you're just sending a string to your controller. You can easily replicate the issue in your console with something like `Post.first.update(flags: "99")`, you should get a similar error.

`flags` should be a collection of ActiveRecord objects as long as it's a `has_many` relationship to another model, and not, say, a column in your `posts` table called `flags`. Another way to update a `has_many` association would be to pass in an array array of `flag_ids`, so both of these options should work:

```rb
Post.first.update(flags: Flag.first(3))
Post.first.update(flag_ids: [1, 2, 3])
```

So, instead of a string, you should send an array of IDs to your controller. Modify the params to accept an array of values instead of a single value like this:

```rb
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :uuid, ..., flag_ids: [])
```

You will also need to update your frontend to send the `flag_ids` as an array. `collection_check_boxes` is usually a good option if you want to select multiple items.

```html
<%= form.collection_check_boxes :flag_ids, Flag.all, :id, :name ... %>
```

Comment: thank you rhelminen it is as you said the has_many relationship in posts, thanks your answer worked!

Comment: Good point to lookup apropriate value consistency if you willl I just have a good laymans eye for correct syntax luckily then was a penultimate issue in the function of the flags, hope your rep goes up, time to use basic ruby some more